# Zapier Formatter Username using Python

Tags: python, zapier

I am pulling in an email from gmail that has some customer data in it, as see below. I would like to use zapier to find the "Name" information then I would like to spilt the name into a First Name & Last Name to import into a spreadsheet.

I know in zapier I have to 1st extract the data as a pattern then in the next step I have to split the data. I am lost on what python I would use to extract the data. I am assuming that I have to find the Name wording in the email body and some how get the Name for the next step but I am unsure how to

## Email Body

```
Event Title:  Some Random Name

Name:   Jon Doe
Username: johndoe123
Company: 
Address:  123 Main St, Washington, DC 20001
Phone:    202-555-0151
Phone2:   202-555-0151
Fax:     
Email:    johndoe123@johndoe.com
```

Comment: Hey SpyFly, welcome to StackOverflow, can you let me know why you've tagged Python here?

Comment: I tagged Python because it appears that zapier uses Pyhton for expressions